# Some hair particles are stiff with dynamics

Tags: particles, physics, hair, dynamic

so I'm currently trying to work on hair dynamics for my rig and I keep running into this problem but don't know how to fix it. I have my rig bending to the left to see how the hair falls and most of it falls but some areas are stiff with no dynamics. I checked the hair weights and it's blue which means it should be the heaviest. I painted it red just to see how the hair reacted and as I expected, the hair did not move. But when the weights are all blue some of those hair particles refuse to move[image] in the image you can see what I'm talking about. I've tried everything to get those hairs to move. The only way to fix it is if I start from scratch again which I've done 4 times already.

Comment: Is there a hidden object that has a *Collision* modifier on it? Is the *Collision* modifier of the body mesh below the *Armature* modifier?

Comment: no, hidden object. And the collision modifier is below the armature modifier. I have other hair particles that react normally to the dynamics on this body mesh. It's just something about this particular particle that just refuses to act normally

Comment: i've tried everything but that section of hair still won't move :( I duplicated the same particle of hair, delete the edit, and started from scratch and all the hair moves normally which is why I'm confused on why this keeps happening

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue recently and what seemed to help was re-keying the particles to a higher resolution. Weight painting them again after that, and then re-simulating.

This worked in Blender 3.4 with the old particle hair system